# Is it possible to study a specific value of a series using a floor function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This question has two parts.

Imagine you have the following series:
$$\frac{i(e^{{i}^{e}}(-1 + s))\zeta'(s)}{k^{i \pi}(1 + (-1 + s) \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-1 + s)^{j}\eta_{j})}$$

Does it make sense to analyze the expression using $j = 0$?

Would taking a floor function of the series allow one to evaluate the series at $j=0$?

Consider the additional example of the value for eta:

$$\eta_{j} = \frac{  (-1)^{j} \lim_{x \to \infty}(\frac{-\log^{1+j}{(x)}}{1+j}) \ + \ \sum_{j=1}^{x} \frac{\log^{j}(j)\Lambda(j)}{j} } {j!}$$

Here, the lower bound for $j$ is $1$, does it then make sense to evaluate the expression for eta at $j=1$?

For evaluating eta at $j=1$, I've computed the following:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{2}\log^{2}{x}$$

Comment: thank you, fixed the missing parenthesis.

Comment: 1+(-1+s)=s, is it what you want? Also, a parenthesis is missing in the numerator.

Comment: the parentheses should be correct now, my apologies.

Comment: You can assume in this context that $(-1+s)^0 = 1$ when $s = 1$.  Generally we take the convention $0^0 = 1$ in power series.  Is that the question?

Comment: BTW, $e^{i^e}$ is a quite whacky constant, where does that come from?

Comment: @JairTaylor yes, more or less.  I was told any analysis of a specific value in a series was an illegal move, but I don't quite believe that.  My main question is whether or not it makes sense to study it when $j=0$, or $j=1$ for example.

Comment: as for $e^{i^{e}}$, it has a specific branch point I'm interested in.

Comment: I still had a misplaced parenthesis, the expression is now correct.

Comment: I assumed you meant if you could evaluate the the $j=0$ term in the series. You mean you want to substitute $j=0$ in the entire expression? No, that doesn't work, because $j$ is a dummy variable.  Your expression for $\eta_j$ doesn't work because $j$ is a dummy variable and cannot be used outside of the sum. Expressions such as $j + \sum_{j=1}^5 j$ don't make sense, or are at least very ambiguous.

Comment: I upvoted; interesting problem (which I'm not qualified to have an opinion on), nicely formatted, interesting work shown.  I'd like to offer (very mild) math jax advice re your mathSE formatting to make your query more readable (perhaps others will disagree): (1) for complicated fractions, you might enlarge them through either \dfrac or \displaystyle (2) you might replace nested parenthesis with something like {..[..(..)..]..} (3) you might consider (for example) \left[...\right] rather than [...] (4) You might (artificially) insert spaces for readability via something like \, or \; or \;\;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding sigma notation.  You cannot evaluate a dummy (bound) variable in an expression.  The expressions you give are a bit convoluted, so here's a simpler example.

Consider the expression $$a = \sum_{j=1}^3 j.$$

In fact $a$ is a constant.  The sigma notation here is just short hand for the sum $a = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6$.  Now how do you set $j = 5$, for example, in this expression?  You can't set $j = 5$ in the expression $\sum_{j=1}^3 j =  1 + 2 + 3$, because $j$ is not a variable in the expression at all; the expression is a constant, $6$.  In fact $j$ is a *bound* variable in the expression, which means it is only used as a short-hand way of describing the sum. The variable $j$ cannot be set to a specific value because $j$ is a *different* value for each term in the sum.  It's $1$ in the first term, $2$ in the second term, $3$ in the third.

Expressions like $$j \cdot \sum_{j=1}^3 j,$$ in which a variable $j$ is used both as the index in the sum and also appears outside of the sum, are invalid, because it is overloading the symbol $j$ and using it in two different ways.  You can arrive at invalid conclusions.  For example, let $j = 2$.  We have

\begin{align*}
12 &= 6j \\
&= j \cdot (1 + 2 + 3)\\
 &= j  \cdot \sum_{j=1}^3 j\\
 &= \sum_{j=1}^3 j^2 \\
&= 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 \\
&= 14.
\end{align*}

For the same reason, your expression for $\eta_j$ is not valid. It uses $j$ both as the index for the sum and as a variable outside the sum.

Comment: Very interesting!  This means that Mathematica gave me an invalid series, because that's where eta came from!  So you can't even use a floor function to evaluate the value of a series at its minimum?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Mathematiica, but perhaps it has some way of dealing with bound variables that's different from typical mathematician's usage.  I don't understand what you mean by using the floor function, can you give an example?

Comment: $$\left \lfloor{12.311}\right \rfloor = 12 $$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Comment: I know what the floor function is, but I mean how do you use it to evaluate the series in the way you describe?

Comment: That's the second part of my question, I don't know if it's even possible.

Comment: No, there's no way.  It's a misunderstanding of the meaning of sigma notation, not anything you can solve with math tricks.  At least, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: apologies, but I think you're wrong, I can take the partial sum using j and x = 1.  Indeed the limit only seems to exist when x =1 for j = 1.

Comment: the only problem is the solution is zero until j = 4, so the partial sum would need to be j = x, and x = 4.

Comment: @floorcat As I've said, your expression for $\eta_j$ doesn't make sense.  You will need to fix that for your question to be valid.

Comment: ...it's wolfram alpha output.

Comment: In this case wolfram alpha is wrong, or at least it does not match usual conventions of mathematicians.  You can presumably fix it just by correcting the notation.  Then your question will be more clear.